# StartsWith() with an array of strings

Tags: c#

Let's say I have an array of strings:

```
string[] greeting = new string[] {"hey", "hello", "hi"};
```

if the user input is any of the following words: "hey" "hello" "hi" then I want the console to print "hey there". This is what I did:

```
 string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

 bool result_a = userInput.StartsWith(greeting);

 if(result_a) { Console.WriteLine("hey there"); }
```

but that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: How about, instead of providing one single example, you actually explain the logic you're trying to implement? For any one example, there are countless ways to make it work, but you'll then complain if we provide a solution that doesn't work for the next example. Your code needs to implement the rules so explain what those rules are. If you can't explain that then you don't understand what you're even trying to do so is it any wonder you can't write code to do it?

Comment: The docs are very clear that StartsWith will only take a string (or char) as argument and not an array of string

Comment: Are you saying, without actually saying, that you want to determine whether the user input starts with any of the values in the array?

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is, whenever the user starts with any of the 3

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

...

         string[] greeting = new string[] {"hey", "hello", "hi"};
         string userInput = Console.ReadLine();         
         bool result_a = greeting.Any(a => userInput.Trim().StartsWith(a));
         if(result_a) { Console.WriteLine("hey there"); }
```

Example: "hi my name is Ali"

Now if you want capital letters to work as well you need to change the line to:

Example: "Hi my name is Ali"

```
bool result_a = greeting.Any(a => userInput.Trim().ToLower().StartsWith(a));
```

---

If what you want is, whenever the user input contains then:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

...

         string[] greeting = new string[] {"hey", "hello", "hi"};
         string userInput = Console.ReadLine();         
         bool result_a = greeting.Any(a => userInput.Trim().Contains(a));
         if(result_a) { Console.WriteLine("hey there"); }
```

Example: "Good morning! hello"

Now if you want capital letters to work as well you need to change the line to:

Example: "Good morning! Hello"

```
bool result_a = greeting.Any(a => userInput.Trim().ToLower().Contains(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] greeting = new string[] { "hey", "hello", "hi" };
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

bool result_a = greeting.Any(x=>x.StartsWith(userInput));

if (result_a) { Console.WriteLine("hey there"); }
if (result_a) { Console.WriteLine($"{greeting.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartsWith(userInput))} there"); }
```

Comment: Did you mean `userInput.StartsWith(x)`?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

try this,bro

```
        List<string> greeting = new List<string>(); 
        greeting.Add("hey");
        greeting.Add("hello");
        greeting.Add("hi");
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

        if (greeting.Contains(userInput.Trim()))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hey there");
        }
```

Comment: This code will not work if you type "hello hi okay" try it out